# Split array with equal indices

Tags: php, arrays

I have a result array which is formatted like the following:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["uf_prop"]=>
    string(2) "GO"
    ["qtd_prop_uf"]=>
    string(3) "612"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["uf_prop"]=>
    string(2) "MG"
    ["qtd_prop_uf"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["uf_prop"]=>
    string(2) "MS"
    ["qtd_prop_uf"]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["uf_prop"]=>
    string(2) "MT"
    ["qtd_prop_uf"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(3) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["uf_prop"]=>
    string(2) "PA"
    ["qtd_prop_uf"]=>
    string(4) "2213"
  }  
  [5]=>
  array(3) {
    ["company"]=>
    string(1) "B"
    ["uf_prop"]=>
    string(2) "PA"
    ["qtd_prop_uf"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
}
```

I want to split and organize this array like the following example if it is possible:

```
company: A 
uf_prop:    GO, MG, MS, MT, PA
qtd_pro_uf: 612, 1, 11, 4, 2213

company: B
uf_prop:    PA
qtd_pro_uf:  6
```

I wish I could divide by 2 or more if there are more companies and then show the states and the amount of a priori stores.

Comment: please select a single language and if it is javascript add the data in literal notation, like a JSON format.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. 
Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide a valid JavaScript data structure for both input and output.

Comment: sorry friends, for passing some confusing information, my first time participating in the community... the Rahul solved my doubt, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel the array structure is like php, so here is php solution.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value['company']]['uf_prop'][]    = $value['uf_prop'];
    $result[$value['company']]['qtd_pro_uf'][] = $value['qtd_pro_uf'];
}
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "company: " . $key . "<br/>";
    echo "uf_prop: " . implode(",", $value['uf_prop']) . "<br/>";
    echo "qtd_pro_uf: " . implode(",", $value['qtd_pro_uf']) . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: thank Rahul you your code worked first, sorry I just passed the information a bit messy, first time in the community

Comment: @luiz_vitorr Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: how to close the topic and mark that solve a question?